# Rails4/devise/rspec issues with redirect testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I got a problem while learnin RSpec and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my controller code:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(item_params)
  if current_user
    @item.user_id = current_user.id
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @item }
   else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end
  end
end
```

My controller_spec:

```
it "renders new page again if validation fails" do
user = User.new(email:"test@email.com", password:"tomandjerry")
sign_in user
post :create, item: { name:"Hi"} 
expect(response).to redirect_to("/items/new")
end
```

And I have

```
include Devise::TestHelpers
```

in my controller_spec and

```
config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
```

in spec_helper.

Seems ok but I run into

```
       ←[31m Expected response to be a redirect to <http://test.host/items/new>
but was a redirect to <http://test.host/users/sign_in>.←[0m
```

error.

Could You please suggest what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not creating the user, you're just initializing the object. Do this instead:

`user = User.create!(email:"test@email.com", password:"tomandjerry")`

As a side note, I would suggest that you use rails fixtures or factory_girl for this purpose.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks.
As to fixtures - I will learn and use that for sure, I just wanted to try some basic testing for now.